# How do you restart php-fpm?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php5

I need to reload my php.ini and there's nothing in the help dialog about restarting it.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

***Note***: prepend `sudo` if not root

- Using SysV Init scripts directly:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart    # typical
  /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart   # debian-style
  /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart # debian-style PHP 7
  ```
- Using service wrapper script

  ```
  service php-fpm restart    # typical
  service php5-fpm restart   # debian-style
  service php7.0-fpm restart # debian-style PHP 7
  ```
- Using Upstart (e.g. ubuntu):

  ```
  restart php7.0-fpm         # typical (ubuntu is debian-based) PHP 7
  restart php5-fpm           # typical (ubuntu is debian-based)
  restart php-fpm            # uncommon
  ```
- Using systemd (newer servers):

  ```
  systemctl restart php-fpm.service    # typical
  systemctl restart php5-fpm.service   # uncommon
  systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service # uncommon PHP 7
  ```

Or whatever the equivalent is on your system.

Comment: What about on a Mac? php-fpm was installed using homebrew. `which php-fpm` gives `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm`.

Comment: @hobbes3 try `brew services restart php56` (if you get an error about no available formula, try a different version e.g. php5 or php55). If you don't have brew services installed, it should install it for you on the first run.

Comment: None of the above worked for me, but this did: `service php-fcgi-mydomain-com restart` And I had to repeat it for every domain from sites-enabled

Comment: This one was the good one for me (centOs) : `systemctl reload php70-php-fpm`

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and this seemed to work:  `systemctl restart php5.6-fpm.service`

Answer (score 30):

For Mac OS X, this is what I do:

Make a script `/usr/local/etc/php/fpm-restart`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Stopping php-fpm..."
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew-php*.plist

echo "Starting php-fpm..."
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew-php*.plist

echo "php-fpm restarted"
exit 0
```

Then:

```
chmod ug+x /usr/local/etc/php/fpm-restart
cd /usr/local/sbin
ln -s /usr/local/etc/php/fpm-restart
```

make sure /usr/local/sbin is in your $PATH

then just call it from the terminal fpm-restart and BOOM!!

Comment: Use `homebrew.mxcl.php*.plist` if it doesn't work

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php#installing-multiple-versions    is case you can't find ths .plist file.

Comment: brew services basically does what your script does.

Answer (score 22):

Usually, `service php5-fpm restart` will do fine, on an up-to-date distribution.

But somtimes, it fails, telling you `restart: Unknown instance:` (or such).

Now, if you do not like to reboot your server, just kill the processes and have a fresh start (edited as of here):

```
$ sudo pkill php5-fpm; sudo service php5-fpm start
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed exactly my issue. (`stop: Unknown instance:`)

Answer (score 13):

This should work:

```
pkill -o -USR2 php-fpm
pkill -o -USR2 php5-fpm
```

Comment: If you installed PHP-FPM via homebrew on a Mac, the first command works a lot better than unload+load'ing the plist

Comment: OSX: `killall php-fpm`

Comment: On OSX the above gave me an error "Unknown user SR2".
Reversing the arguments fixed it: "pkill -USR2 -o php-fpm"

Comment: Exactly what I needed to restart FPM in a container, thanks!

Comment: I am using the pre-installed, or bundled with xcode, version of php and its associated -fpm for some reason, and not through Homebrew.  Just thought I should use what's there already.  I am using a combination of `php-fpm --prefix /usr/local`, making some directories under that one it needs, and as @Keeth has stated, `pkill -USR2 -o php-fpm`, checking with `pgrep -l fpm`, and the PIDs do indeed change!  I had no plist files or services to take advantage of mentioned by some of the other answers.

Answer (score 12):

For Mac OSX `brew services restart php56` worked for me.

Comment: yup, works for me also. Mac osx

Answer (score 11):

I had a problem restarting php7-fpm, because I didn't knew how exactly the service was named. This function gave me the answer:

`service --status-all`

php7-fpm service in my Ubuntu was called `php7.0-fpm`, so I did:

`service php7.0-fpm restart`

Comment: +1 for `service --status-all`

Answer (score 6):

php-fpm will restart if you send a USR2 signal to the main process:

```
sudo kill -USR2 php-fpm_main_process_id
```

So we just need to instruct php-fpm to record its pid somewhere. In this example, I'll assume you want to save it at `/etc/private/php-fpm.pid`, and that php-fpm runs as user _php. First, add this line to the configuration file:

```
pid = /etc/php-fpm.pid
```

Then create the file `/etc/php-fpm.pid`, and make sure php-fpm has permission to modify it:

```
$ cd /etc
$ sudo touch php-fpm.pid
$ sudo chown _php php-fpm.pid
$ sudo chmod 644 php-fpm.pid
```

Now, next time php-fpm starts, you'll be able to get its pid and restart it like this:

```
$ cat /etc/php-fpm.pid
815
$ sudo kill -USR2 815
```

Or you can combine these into a single command:

```
$ sudo kill -USR2 `cat /etc/private/php-fpm.pid`
```

Comment: I am liking @dialt0ne's and @Keeth's `pkill ...` answer & comment above more; shorter and simpler.

Comment: this is better,  and nice explanation.   the pkill runs the risk, if you don't get the processes matched correctly,  of killing off your other PHP clusters if you happen to have them running on the same box (yes this is bad practice).

Answer (score 3):

For me I had just upgraded via apt and the service restart wasn't working. I ended up needing to kill the existing processes before it worked using: killall php5-fpm

Answer (score 2):

To allow the PHP-FPM restart script to work, you must use specify a PID file in your php-fpm.conf file. i.e.

```
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
```

The default value for pid in php-fpm.conf is nothing, which means to not create a PID file, which means that the restart script can't tell which process to end during the restart.

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 7

```
sudo systemctl enable php-fpm // Just incase is disabled. Also ensures it starts automatically with the server

sudo systemctl start php-fpm  // Start the service

sudo systemctl stop php-fpm   // Stop the service

sudo systemctl status php-fpm  // View status
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16 with php 5.6 fpm.

```
 /etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

On RedHat / CentOS 7 using [PHP 7 from softwarecollections.org](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php70/)

```
service rh-php70-php-fpm start
service rh-php70-php-fpm stop
service rh-php70-php-fpm reload
service rh-php70-php-fpm restart
service rh-php70-php-fpm status
```

**or if you're using systemctl:**

```
systemctl start rh-php70-php-fpm
systemctl stop rh-php70-php-fpm
systemctl reload rh-php70-php-fpm
systemctl restart rh-php70-php-fpm
systemctl status rh-php70-php-fpm
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to find the name of php-fpm service is to search for it:

```
systemctl -l --type service --all | grep fpm
```

Comment: You can make it simpler: `systemctl list-units *fpm*`

Answer (score 0):

For old versions of debian & ubuntu - php 5.6 it will be

```
 /etc/init.d/php-fpm56 restart
 service php-fpm56 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

1. Open Services in the  Management Console:

   ```
   Start -> Run -> "services.msc" -> OK
   ```
2. Select `php-fpm` from the list
3. Rightclick and select restart

Answer (score 0):

On Alpine with nginx this is working here:

To kill all php-fpm7 processes:

`kill $(ps -o pid,comm | grep php-fpm7 | awk '{print $1}')`

To start php-fpm7:

`php-fpm7`

Answer (score 0):

To list systemd services on CentOS/RHEL 7.x+ use

> systemctl

To list all services:

> systemctl list-unit-files

Where you can find service named * php-fpm * copy service name and run the following command

> systemctl restart ea-php72-php-fpm.service

**NOTE :** **ea-php72-php-fpm.service** user your service name

Answer (score -2):

Another method for MaxOS

Open ActivityMonitor, search php-fpm, find the pid.

Open terminal, use `kill [pid]` to stop php-fpm

Then `php-fpm` on terminal to start it.

If there is error information that 127.0.0.1:9000 Already in use, just ignore that.

Refresh Nginx page, should see php.ini changes take effects.

Comment: What is MaxOS? Just running `php-fpm` will most probably run it under the wrong user; ignoring error messages is never a good idea.